# Obfuscated Javascript in an exploit kit using Array's constructor

Tags: javascript, firefox, exploit

I noticed some obfuscated Javascript in an Exploit Kit

```
> a = []["constructor"]
Array() { [native code] }
> b = a["constructor"]
Function() { [native code] }
> b("console.log('a');")
anonymous() {
    console.log('a');
}
> b("console.log('a');")()
a
```

or in other words

```
> [].constructor.constructor("console.log('a');")()
a
```

Can someone explain what's happening here? What's the constructor of a constructor of an Array?

Comment: You can enter `[].constructor.constructor` into any JS console and find out for yourself.

Comment: In case you're curious, the constructor of `Function` is also a `Function`, so it's a circular relationship beyond that. Here's the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) for `Function`

Comment: Yes, that's the output of a JS console. The key here (that I was missing) is that Function prototype takes a string literal and does eval on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[].constructor.constructor("console.log('a');")()
```

> a

SO.. what is this?

```
[].constructor.constructor
```

> Function() { [native code] }

Ahha... so it is just a way to invoke the `Function` constructor, which takes a string to eval... then the final parens invoke it.

```
Function("console.log('a')")()  // Works with or without `new`
```

> a

Comment: Thanks. Here's the constructor's prototype new Function ([arg1[, arg2[, ...argN]],] functionBody)
Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

Answer (score 0):

You can enter `[].constructor.constructor` into any JS console and find out for yourself.

```
[].constructor
  -> Array() { [native code] }
[].constructor.constructor
  -> Function() { [native code] }
[].constructor.constructor("console.log('a');")()
 -> a
```